# Javascript program to print all stars pattern in single code with 2 for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need Javascript code to print all star patterns using a single program with only 2 for loops. I tried the following code but it prints only diamond shape.

```
var spaces = " ";
var rows = "* ";
while(rows.length < 200) {
    spaces += spaces; // doubles length each time
    rows += rows; // ditto
}

function diamond(n) {
    n = parseInt(n, 10);
    var i, s;
    // top: 1 to n
    console.log("<pre>");
    for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        // write n-i spaces:
        console.log(spaces.substring(0,n-i));
        // then write i asterisk+space sets:
        console.log( rows.substring(0,i+i) + "\n");
    }
    // bottom: n-1 down to 1
    for(i = n-1; i >= 1; --i) {
        // write n-i spaces:
        console.log( spaces.substring(0,n-i) );
        // then write i asterisk+space sets:
        console.log( rows.substring(0,i+i) + "\n" );
    }
    console.log("</pre>");
}
diamond(9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let star = "";
for(let i=1; i<=50; i++) {
  
  for(let j=1; j<=i; j++) {
    star += "*";
  }
  star += "\n";
}
console.log(star);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many star patterns, you didn't specify which ones you're interested in.
Anyway, if you can read and translate simple C code to Javascript, here is a link to 9 star pattern you could try

http://cbasicprogram.blogspot.it/2012/03/star-patterns.html

Star pattern algorithms are generally very simple to understand in every language since they are used as beginner exercises. If you don't find anything JS related, try and search in another language.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the switch case to print out the star patterns:

```
for (let x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
  switch (x) {
    case 1:
      console.log("*");
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log("**");
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log("***");
      break;
    case 4:
      console.log("****");
      break;
    case 5:
      console.log("*****");
      break;
    case 6:
      console.log("******");
      break;
    case 7:
      console.log("*******");
      break;
    case 8:
      console.log("********");
      break;
    case 9:
      console.log("*********");
      break;
  }
}
```